# Is it possible to use awk to print all line in a file and then do a command on a single column?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I was wondering if it is possible to print all lines in a file using AWK and then selecting one of those columns in the file to hash that value using this command:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
```

I am using the read command at the moment but it seems to write extremely slow.  Here's what I have at the moment:

```
while IFS="," read -ra line;
do
    if [ "${line[1]}" != "" ]; then
        echo -n "${line[*]}, Hash Value:"; echo "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
    else
        if [ "${line[1]}" == "" ]; then
            echo "${line[*]}, Hash Value: None";
        fi
    fi
done
```

So I guess ultimately what I am saying is, how can I use AWK instead to print all the line and do a command on a specific column?  Looking to speed up the process of the read.  Also, is it possible to use AWK to print columns of all files in a directory?

Thanks guys!

## UPDATE

Below is code containing the conversion to DOS to UNIX format of all text files.  Below that is some of the output to unix.txt.  Lastly, below that is my script.

**dos2unix**

```
$ dos2unix *.txt
dos2unix: converting file unix.txt to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file woohoo.txt to Unix format ...
```

**unix.txt Input**

```
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
```

**unix.txt Output**

```
$ ./trial.sh < unix.txt
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value: c9b674deec9973f4d0feb83433d6db0b4ea5012a
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value:
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value:
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value: 2a8db89cc6f4ccdc0ce423011e869cb8b29b1003
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value:
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value:
```

**Script**

```
gawk -F',' '
function hash(val, var) 
    {
    if (val == "") { 
           var = "None" 
          }
              else {
                    "echo \"" val "\" | openssl dgst -sha1" | getline var
                   sub(/.* /,"",var) 
                    }
              return var 
                    }
{ printf "%s, Hash Value: %s\n", $0, hash($2) } '
```

As you can see when the script is ran against unix.txt, the values that contain a second column are not hashing.  The first few rows are hashing though.  Not sure what is happening but it should work.

Comment: How slow is "extremely slow"?

Comment: @Vaughn Well, I have multiple files that need to be processed and one file is 255MB.  That one file probably takes 3-4 hours on my machine.  I would like to eventually only take 15-20 minutes to complete a file of that size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt         
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
7051,95230163,-1,53200703
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013
$                       
$ cat trial.sh
gawk -F',' '
function hash(val, var) {
    if (val == "") { 
        var = "None" 
    }
    else {
        cmd = "echo \"" val "\" | openssl dgst -sha1"
        cmd | getline var
        close(cmd)
        sub(/.* /,"",var) 
    }
    return var 
}
{ printf "%s, Hash Value: %s\n", $0, hash($2) }
'
$ 
$ ./trial.sh < input.txt
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value: c9b674deec9973f4d0feb83433d6db0b4ea5012a
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value: c9b674deec9973f4d0feb83433d6db0b4ea5012a
7051,95230163,-1,53200703, Hash Value: c9b674deec9973f4d0feb83433d6db0b4ea5012a
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value: 2a8db89cc6f4ccdc0ce423011e869cb8b29b1003
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value: 2a8db89cc6f4ccdc0ce423011e869cb8b29b1003
53200703,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:03 PDT 2013, Hash Value: 2a8db89cc6f4ccdc0ce423011e869cb8b29b1003
```

Note that above is GNU-awk specific as it uses coprocesses to pipe the output of the shell command into being read by getline.

Also, now that I see your sample input contains many duplicates, this would probably be more efficient by avoiding the external command and pipes for duplicate key fields by just storing the hash value the first time it's calculated and using it thereafter:

```
$ cat trial.sh               
gawk -F',' '
function hash(val) {
    if ( !(val in map) ) {
        if (val == "") { 
            map[val] = "None" 
        }
        else {
            cmd = "echo \"" val "\" | openssl dgst -sha1"
            cmd | getline map[val]
            close(cmd)
            sub(/.* /,"",map[val])
        }
    }
    return map[val]
}
{ printf "%s, Hash Value: %s\n", $0, hash($2) }
'
```

And yes, of course you can use awk to print whatever you want from all files in a directory:

```
awk '{ print <whatever> }' /dir/*
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what I have been looking to do in a quick manner as of yet.  Only issue is that it's not printing the values after the "Hash Value:" part after the first line.  Going to see if I can figure out why.

Comment: If you copy/paste your command and it's output into the original question you asked, we can tell you what the problem is. Also run `gawk --version`.

Comment: I just noticed you said "...after the first line" so that tells me there's something wrong with your input file since the awk script won't behave differently between lines. Probably your input file was created on Windows and so has spurious control-Ms at the end of each line. Run `cat -v` on it to check and `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.  I think the issue is that all columns are separated by commas, but I didn't think something like this should matter with gawk.  I'm going to try and convert to unix type and see if it fixes the issue.  I'll post some results shortly.

Comment: Of course it matters. I see now thatyou had set `IFS=","` in your shell script, I didn't notice that before. This is why you should provide sample input and expected output when you post a question, so the people trying to help you don't need to figure some out for themselves. I'll update my script to use `-F','`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I'm relatively new as a poster on this forum and also relatively new to shell scripting.  I am still having some issues with results.  I'm updating my post now so maybe you can see what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry, input was added

Comment: I think I know why it's not printing the rest of the values, but it's strange why it's doing this.  The values that are repeats are not printing.

Comment: When posting input/output, post the smallest set that demonstrates your problem. I'll edit it for you.

Comment: OK, I see the problem, I just needed to close the pipe to getline after each line of input. I've updated my answer now using your provided sample input.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm.  Thanks so much for the help.  I'll make sure to +1 when I have enough reps.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I also just added a new version of the script that'd probably be more efficient given the sample input you posted.

Comment: The update is even faster than the original.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

It its possible to run a shell command from `awk`. You just need proper quoting, like this:

```
echo "123" | awk '{ print $0 | "openssl dgst -sha1 | sed '"'s/^.* //'"'" }'
```

output:

```
a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but used another example for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd do something like:

```
cat file
awk '{print $2}' file | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
```

This uses `cat` to copy all lines in the file to standard output, and then uses `awk` to print the values in column 2, which is piped to `openssl` and `sed`.  Is there a reason you can't do that?

If the input is coming from a command (so you can't reread it), you have to work harder, but you explicitly say 'from a file' so I assume this isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input, used another example though.

Comment: If you want a hash value for each line, then what I gave isn't what you need — but what I gave is one reasonable interpretation of "print all lines in a file using AWK and then selecting one of those columns in the file to hash that value".  I suppose 'that value' vs 'those values' might be the clue I missed.